# Multiple optimal solutions for 0/1 Knapsack problem

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

A 0/1 knapsack problem with a maximum capacity constraint can have more than one optimal solution yielding the same profit but with/without the same capacity. How can we generate the set of all optimal soultions from the dp matrix.
For example;

```
Capacity [4, 2, 5, 2]
Value [10, 4, 10, 4]
Maximum capacity: 7
Selected: 1,2 
Total Value: 14
DP matrix:
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10],
 [0, 0, 4, 4, 10, 10, 14, 14],
 [0, 0, 4, 4, 10, 10, 14, 14],
 [0, 0, 4, 4, 10, 10, 14, 14]]
```

Here (1,2),(1,4),(2,3) and (3,4) gives the same profit, but usual backtracking from bottom right element in dp matrix will give (1,2) as the solution. How can we find all such combinations?

Comment: @user3386109 If we can find *any* solution from the matrix at all, why can't we find any other the same way?

Comment: @user3386109 I'm not convinced. And I for example do see a path for (3,4). I might try coding it tomorrow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can find all solution, but it could become very inefficient (since there could be exponential number of optimal solutions)

You need to go back on the DP matrix from end, and "spawn" a new branch everytime you encounter a valid route (basically, do a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on the matrix, where nodes are cells, and edges are valid transitions between them, while allowing repeating already visited nodes to discover all paths).

Pseudo code:

```
// i, j are indices of current element
// so_far is the list holding the current valid solution
FindSolutions(i, j, so_far):
  // Stop clause: Check if this is the last element added as a valid solution
  if j == 0:
    so_far.append(i)
    yield_copy_of(so_far)
    so_far.remove_last()
  for next_item in range(0, i):
    // This checks if you could move from next_item to current state using i
    // no boundary condition here, you should probably check it
    if DP[next_item][j-weights[i]] + value[i] == DP[i][j]:
      so_far.append(i)
      FindSolutions(next_item, j-weights[i], so_far)
      so_far.remove_last()
```

Comment: Didn't think through the details (like, maybe we should start at all six cells with value 14), but that's how I intended to do it. The usual backwards recreation, simply trying *all* possible paths instead of just one.  I still wonder how user3386109 imagined to find one path in a way that couldn't find others.